# PyQt5 Interface Crashes When I Try to Send&Receive List From Function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyserial, python-3.7

I am beginner of Python. 
I am trying to create interface for serial communication. On my app, there are 4 variable and each one 2 bytes. And I have starter,command, source and destination bytes. So, totally 4*2+4= 12 bytes list I have.
I am trying to send this list and take back.
There is no console error but when I try to send list, it is crashing.

```
ui.SendAll_Button.clicked.connect(lambda: com.send(self.newPackage))
```

If I send normal list, without function, it works. But **newPackage** is in the **ValuetoHex** function, it does not work.
I am leaving my code here:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import Max2828_Window as myWindow
import Max2828_WindowEdit as EditModule
import serial
from time import sleep
import struct

con = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600 , timeout = 1)
error_message  = [0X65, 0X72, 0X72, 0X6F, 0X72]
starter_byte   = 0XAA
source_byte    = 0X01
max2828_byte   = 0X02
max5866_byte   = 0X03
command_byte   = 0XBB
byte_1         = 0X00
byte_2         = 0X00
byte_3         = 0X00
byte_4         = 0X00
byte_5         = 0X00
byte_6         = 0X00
byte_7         = 0X00
byte_8         = 0X00


class Communication():
    Package = [starter_byte, source_byte, max2828_byte, command_byte,
           byte_1, byte_2, byte_3, byte_4,
           byte_5, byte_6, byte_7, byte_8]
    def send(self, PackageList):
        print(str(PackageList))
        con.write(PackageList)

    def receive(self,PackageList):
         our_buffer = []
         counter = 1
         while counter <= len(PackageList):
             msg = con.read() 
             our_buffer.append(msg)
             print ("received " + str("".join( chr(x) for x in msg)))             
             print (str(our_buffer))
             if len(our_buffer) >= len(PackageList):
                 our_buffer = None
             counter = counter + 1
##             sleep(1)


    def main(self, PackageList):       
        self.send(PackageList)
        self.receive(PackageList)
##com = Communication()
##com.main()
```

also this is main page:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import Max2828_Window as myWindow
import Max2828_Communication as myCommunication
import serial
from time import sleep
import struct
import os
starter_byte   = 0XAA
source_byte    = 0X01
max2828_byte   = 0X02
max5866_byte   = 0X03
command_byte   = 0XBB
class WindowEdit(object):
    def mainloop(self):
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        ui = myWindow.Ui_MainWindow()
        MainWindow = ui.callMain()    
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        self.ValuetoHex(ui)
##########
        com = myCommunication.Communication()
##########    Menu Side
        ui.actionExit.triggered.connect(ui.close_application)
##########    ScrollBar Side
        ui.RFFrequency_ScrollBar.valueChanged.connect(lambda: ui.ScrollBarValue(ui.RFFrequency_ScrollBar, ui.RFFrequency_Line))
        ui.PADACOutputBias_ScrollBar.valueChanged.connect(lambda: ui.ScrollBarValue(ui.PADACOutputBias_ScrollBar, ui.PADACOutputBias_Line))
        ui.RXVGAGain_ScrollBar.valueChanged.connect(lambda: ui.ScrollBarValue(ui.RXVGAGain_ScrollBar, ui.RXVGAGain_Line))
        ui.TXVGAGain_ScrollBar.valueChanged.connect(lambda: ui.ScrollBarValue(ui.TXVGAGain_ScrollBar, ui.TXVGAGain_Line))

        ui.RFFrequency_Line.editingFinished.connect(lambda: ui.RFFrequency_ScrollBar.setSliderPosition(int(ui.RFFrequency_Line.text())))
        ui.PADACOutputBias_Line.editingFinished.connect(lambda: ui.PADACOutputBias_ScrollBar.setSliderPosition(int(ui.PADACOutputBias_Line.text())))
        ui.RXVGAGain_Line.editingFinished.connect(lambda: ui.RXVGAGain_ScrollBar.setSliderPosition(int(ui.RXVGAGain_Line.text())))
        ui.TXVGAGain_Line.editingFinished.connect(lambda: ui.TXVGAGain_ScrollBar.setSliderPosition(int(ui.TXVGAGain_Line.text())))
##########  Button Side
        def removeCombobox():
            if ( ui.Setups_ComboBox.currentText() == 'Evaluation Defaults' or ui.Setups_ComboBox.currentText() == "LastPowerDown" ):
                pass
            else:
                ui.Setups_ComboBox.removeItem(ui.Setups_ComboBox.currentIndex())  
        ui.Del_Button.clicked.connect(lambda: removeCombobox())
##    ui.SendAll_Button.clicked.connect(lambda: com.main(myCommunication.Package))

########## Line Edit Side
        ui.RFFrequency_Line.setText(str( ui.RFFrequency_ScrollBar.value()))
        ui.PADACOutputBias_Line.setText(str( ui.PADACOutputBias_ScrollBar.value()))
        ui.RXVGAGain_Line.setText(str( ui.RXVGAGain_ScrollBar.value()))
        ui.TXVGAGain_Line.setText(str( ui.TXVGAGain_ScrollBar.value()))

        ui.RFFrequency_Line.editingFinished.connect(lambda: ui.CheckingLines(ui.RFFrequency_ScrollBar, ui.RFFrequency_Line))
        ui.PADACOutputBias_Line.editingFinished.connect(lambda: ui.CheckingLines(ui.PADACOutputBias_ScrollBar, ui.PADACOutputBias_Line))
        ui.RXVGAGain_Line.editingFinished.connect(lambda: ui.CheckingLines(ui.RXVGAGain_ScrollBar, ui.RXVGAGain_Line))
        ui.TXVGAGain_Line.editingFinished.connect(lambda: ui.CheckingLines(ui.TXVGAGain_ScrollBar, ui.TXVGAGain_Line))
########## Communication Side


        ui.RFFrequency_ScrollBar.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.ValuetoHex(ui))
        ui.PADACOutputBias_ScrollBar.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.ValuetoHex(ui))
        ui.RXVGAGain_ScrollBar.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.ValuetoHex(ui))
        ui.TXVGAGain_ScrollBar.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.ValuetoHex(ui))
        print("hello")
        x = []
        for i in self.newPackage:
            x.append(i)
            print (i)
        print("hello")
        for i in x:
            print (i)
        ui.SendAll_Button.clicked.connect(lambda: com.send(self.newPackage))
        print("How are you")
##############    
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def ValuetoHex(self,ui):           
        ValueofRFFrequency      = ui.RFFrequency_ScrollBar.value()
        ValueofPADACOutputBias  = ui.PADACOutputBias_ScrollBar.value()
        ValueofRXVGAGain        = ui.RXVGAGain_ScrollBar.value()
        ValueofTXVGAGain        = ui.TXVGAGain_ScrollBar.value()
        RF   = struct.pack('>h', ValueofRFFrequency)            
        RF   = RF.hex()[:]
        PADA = struct.pack('>h', ValueofPADACOutputBias)
        PADA = PADA.hex()[:]
        RX   = struct.pack('>h', ValueofRXVGAGain)
        RX   = RX.hex()[:]
        TX   = struct.pack('>h', ValueofTXVGAGain)
        TX   = TX.hex()[:]
##            part_1 = format(value, '#X')[:4]
##            part_2 = format(value, '#X')[-2:]
##            global newPackage
        self.newPackage = [format(starter_byte, 'X'), format(source_byte, 'X')[:2].zfill(2),
                      format(max2828_byte, 'X')[:2].zfill(2), format(command_byte, 'X'),
                      RF[:2], RF[-2:], PADA[:2], PADA[-2:], RX[:2], RX[-2:], TX[:2], TX[-2:] ]
        for i in self.newPackage:
            print (i)
##            com.main( s )
##            RFValue = ui.RFFrequency_ScrollBar.value()
##            RFValue_2 = int(RFValue % 100)
##            RFValue_1 = int((RFValue - RFValue_2) / 100)
##            
##            byte_1 = hex(RFValue_1)
##            myCommunication.byte_2 = hex(RFValue_2)
##            
##            print(RFValue_1.__format__('#04X') + "  " + RFValue_2.__format__('#04X'))
##            print(str(RFValue_1) + "  " + str(RFValue_2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Edit = WindowEdit()
    Edit.mainloop()
```

Also there is another page, created by PyQt. If it is necessary, I can upload it.
There is no error message or console error. Only app is crashing when I click send button. I you want to suggest anything about my code, don't hesitate. I am beginner and I want to learn. Thank you.
(This is my first message, thank you from now on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem in code.
foo.hex() function is returning "string" type. However, serial.write function needs "int" type. Thats why my app was crashing.
And, I also add sqlite3 DB to my app. Also I don't use Max2828_Communication lib anymore.

Here is my latest code,
https://github.com/mucahitkayadan/Python